# How much of the fifth year option salary is guaranteed?

Tags: american-football, nfl, finances

Given that teams have to pick up a players fifth year option in the summer before their forth year, how much is guaranteed?

IF a player is on the bubble before the forth year but then really sucks the forth year, how hard is it to dump him?